# How much voltage can a contactor withstand?

Tags: contactor

I tried searching, but unfortunately did not find an answer. Given a typical 24V AC (or DC) contactor, how much voltage can the contactor control circuit withstand? Will it be damaged by mains electricity?

Comment: Completely dependent on the contactor.

Comment: Two different voltage ratings are possible; coil-to-frame and coil-terminal differential voltage both are subject to  limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contactors are similar to relays- they are electromechanical devices operated by a coil. The datasheet for the particular device may include some information on permissible coil voltage tolerances that will guarantee operation and avoid premature failure (especially over temperature).

Applying much more than the rated voltage will cause the coil to overheat and it may be destroyed. Certainly mains voltage on a 24V coil (AC or DC) would cause it to fail within a very short time. Even faster (essentially instantly) if it has some kind of coil suppression, as some do.

Comment: @Stephro Pefhany Will it short or have no current going through it, if damaged?

Comment: If the coil insulation is damaged the coil current may go up a lot then go down. The contacts should be open if the coil current is very low, though it's possible to imagine a bad design where severe coil overheating caused the contacts to jam on.